# Нужна ли запятая между соподчиненными придаточными предложениями?

Tags: союзы

У Розенталя: Врач сказал, что больному нужен покой, и если мы не хотим тревожить его, то должны выйти из палаты – союз и соединяет соподчиненные придаточные части;

Правильно ли я понимаю, что соподчиненные придаточные части - это

1) больному нужен покой (простое предложение)
2) если мы не хотим тревожить его, то должны выйти из палаты (сложноподчиненное предложение)

Но с другой стороны, соподчиненные придаточныечасти, соединенные союзом И, не разделяются запятой:

Когда дождик пошел и все вокруг засверкало, мы по тропе... вышли из леса. (М. П.).

Тогда почему в первом предложении перед И должна стоять запятая?

Answer (score 3):

**Врач сказал, что больному нужен покой, и если мы не хотим тревожить его, то должны выйти из палаты.**

Запятая не ставится, если союзом И соединены **однородные** придаточные предложения, например: Врач сказал, что **больному нужен покой и мы должны выйти из палаты.**

(В этом случае придаточные образуют единую фразу, которая читается без паузы, этим объясняется отсутствие запятой).

В приведенном примере (при наличии двойного союза ЕСЛИ...ТО) **союз И соединяет придаточное и сложноподчиненное предложение,**  а не два придаточных.